# How to increase size of Linux disk in chromebook?

Tags: chromebook

Asus chromebox3 with 8 GB Ram, 32 GB SSD, with Linux Crostini enabled

Notification says Linux is low on space so I plug in a blank 8 Gb USB drive (which is recognized and mounted in /mnt/media/removable/UUI), and I click "resize linux disk" and see it's current size is 7.5 GB ....however the right end of the slider only goes to 7.9 GB (!!!)

How do I increase the space available to Linux beyond 7.9 GB?   I thought adding USB or SD storage would help, but no?